# addView adds the view but it's not showing it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know this has already been asked, but I tried everything and I couldn't solve my problem.

When I create the views programmatically, they are definitely added. I checked in the debugger and everything is in it's place, even the parent view gets bigger in height because they are using space. But I can't see them. It's like they are below other views or invisible (but they are not. I checked many times...).

[image]

This is the xml code where I'm trying to insert the views. I want to insert them where the cursor is (where it's tagged information). I only have it there to show you how it will look like in the end, but this part will be added programmatically.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llhTestItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvInformationTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    fontPath="fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"
                    android:text="Sub title: "/> <!-- tvInformationTitle -->

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvInformation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    fontPath="fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf"
                    android:text="information"/> <!-- tvInformation -->

        </LinearLayout> <!-- information -->
```

Below you can see the code that I'm using to add the views just like in the xml above.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SetupViewerHolder holder, int position) {
    CardViewItem cardViewItem = cardViewItemList.get(position);
    holder.tvTitle.setText(cardViewItem.getCardTitle());
    for (int i = 0; i < cardViewItem.getInformationList().size(); i++){

        //region Create llhItem
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llhItemParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        llhItemParams.topMargin = dipToPixels(6);

        LinearLayout llhItem = new LinearLayout(context);
        llhItem.setLayoutParams(llhItemParams);
        llhItem.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        //endregion

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvInformationsParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //region Create tvInformationTitle
        TextView tvInformationTitle = new TextView(context);
        tvInformationTitle.setLayoutParams(tvInformationsParams);
        tvInformationTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
            tvInformationTitle.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.OpenSansRegular);
        } else {
            tvInformationTitle.setTextAppearance(R.style.OpenSansRegular);
        }
        tvInformationTitle.setText(cardViewItem.getInformationList().get(i)[0]);
        //endregion

        //region Create tvInformation
        TextView tvInformation = new TextView(context);
        tvInformation.setLayoutParams(tvInformationsParams);
        tvInformation.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
            tvInformation.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.OpenSansLight);
        } else {
            tvInformation.setTextAppearance(R.style.OpenSansLight);
        }
        tvInformation.setText(cardViewItem.getInformationList().get(i)[1]);
        //endregion

        llhItem.addView(tvInformationTitle);
        llhItem.addView(tvInformation);

        holder.llvInformation.addView(llhItem);
    }
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to have a recycler view, and each item has only one title, one overflow button, but can have multiple information rows.
Here is a print of this, which I had hard coded in xml previously as a prototype.

[image]

I know of some alternative ways of doing this that might work, but for now I would like to have it like this, since everything is working like it should, the views are just "not visible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling `invalidate()` after adding the view? Like this:

```
holder.llvInformation.addView(llhItem);
holder.llvInformation.invalidate();
```

Comment: I wonder if there's something wrong with the layout params. Is at least the llhItem itself visible? For instance, if you set a bg color to it, can you see it?

Comment: Setting a bg worked, then i realized that for some reason, the text is invisible if i don't set a color for it. Thank you so much ! 
Dammit, in the end its always something simple... :)

Comment: `invalidate()` after the `addView(..)` had no effect in my case, but calling `addView()` inside `post {}` worked

Answer (score 5):

Had to use layout.post

```
holder.llvInformation.post( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        holder.llvInformation.addView(llhItem);
    }
});
```